# Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I had Eclipse Indigo installed on my computer with the Android plugin and it was working perfectly for about two weeks. Today, I updated java and quicktime then restarted my computer. When it booted back up, eclipse had completely vanished - all the program files have completely disappeared. When I try to reinstall it, I get an error message that says

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your directory structure where the SW was installed is completely gone?  This would be a pretty strange error....

Comment: Yes. Everything related to eclipse, except for my project folder, is gone

Comment: you don't say which OS you're using, so I'll suggest that you search for "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" and apply the fixes found for your OS therein

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing that, haven't found anything helpful yet. I'm running Win 7 64bit

Comment: I had the same issue in Ubuntu 12.10... all I had to do was change the corresponding paths on the eclipse.ini file and everything was back to normal.

Comment: once again another seemingly random error in Eclipse...I would use Juno as it seems to be more stable.

Comment: Using Kepler 4.3.1 here. I've gotten this error (eclipse executables and a few other important files were gone) immediately after I've uninstalled a nightly release (21.11.2013) of VJET. I have no idea what caused it and why I've deserved this.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte/59091837#59091837

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That sounds pretty bad and weird. But reinstalling isn't that hard - download, unzip, change the default memory allocation, run Eclipse, install necessary plugins and features.

And almost all of the important preferences are in your workspace. The only important one I can think of outside of the workspace is the aforementioned memory allocation, which you can set on the command line or in the ECLIPSE.INI file.

Comment: "Unzip" was the step I forgot.. After unzipping the install package I clicked the executable and Eclipse opened up just as I had left it (it remembered which files I had open) - I did have to re-install the ADT plugin though. Strange situation, I still have absolutely no idea what happened.

Comment: Before reinstalling try to launch it with the original eclipse.ini file

Comment: You can also try System Restore if your under windows which the problem may suggest that you are. In my case that fixed this issue.

Comment: I got this same error message, on an instance of LiClipse (Eclipse distro for Python) which had been upgraded from 1.x to 2.x to 3.0.6, and had several other Eclipse features installed. On Mac OS X 10.10.5.  This install worked until I updated or removed any of 5 features. Once broken, Time Machine restored a working LiClipse. In the end, what worked was to note the features I had installed, then make a fresh install of the current version of LiClipse, then reinstall my extra Eclipse features. Yes, reinstallation isn't that hard, because the most important preferences persist.

Comment: "change the default memory allocation"?

Comment: "reinstalling isn't that hard" - clearly you've never installed third-party plugins

Comment: I've installed 3rd-party plugins hundreds of times.

Comment: What a great ide

Answer (score 116):

I've just encountered the same issue. The problem for me was Windows 7 default unzipper program. It has a problem when it encounters files that have a deep file structure. I read about this issue some time ago but can't recall the article. Fix for me is to unzip the Eclipse download using WinZip (or some other tool which does'nt have this issue).

Comment: I wouldn't believe this if I haven't experienced it by myself but it solved my problem!

Comment: @yoshi glad it solved your issue,nice to know answering a question that has already been answered has proved useful

Comment: Had this issue on XP, unzipped with 7-zip instead and now it launches.

Comment: on XP 32 bit I had to: Move the zip file to the root. Rename it to e.zip. Open in it in 7Zip and rename the "eclipse" folder in there to "e". Unzip it - rename the extracted folder to "eclipse". Bonkers.

Comment: Unbelievable, but using WinRar instead of windows' internal zip-program really did solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing.  Here I am 4.5 years later, using Windows 10 with the latest upgrades, and still needing this answer.  Microsoft really wants people using Linux I guess.

Comment: Win10 + 7zip. Had to change location to create a shorter path.

Comment: same issue for me on mac.  this did it for me gunzip -c neoclipse-1.9.5-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.tar.gz | tar xopf -

Answer (score 43):

Check eclipse.ini, there are two entries like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
```

For some twisted reason jars have version in their name - so if you upgrade/have two different version of eclipse( while eclipse.ini is either linked or provided as system wide conf file for eclipse ) it will cause above error.

Comment: I kept the original eclipse.ini under a different name and using it again 'solves' the problem.

Comment: Thank you - this helped, as the launcher.library was unreachable by the current user.  My eclipse.ini had the startup pointing to the jar located where it was installed, and the launcher.library stored under c:\users\<not-the-current-user>\.p2 - so I moved the .p2 folder to the install folder - now all users can run it.

Comment: I had problem also in the -vm path

Answer (score 22):

During unzip in a cygwin directory on Win7, *.exe* and *.dll* need to be given executable mode.  This is the solution from a mintty (or other `$TERM`) terminal run with cygwin on windows 7:

```
me@mymachine ~/eclipse
$ find . -name "*.dll" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

tried with Juno (eclipse 4.2) freshly unzipped, cygwin 1.7.something

Comment: Looks like there are many possible problems and solutions.  For me, the key was "cygwin".  - Thanks

Comment: just had the same problem and indeed, executables as well as dlls were simply not unzipped with the `x` permission.

Comment: Also, I did run the unzip on a linux box to see if it was the cygwin `unzip`'s fault, but it isn't. The file permissions are just incorrect in the zip file itself, as you can see with `zipinfo -l eclipse-java-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip| grep -E '\.(exe|dll)'`.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS ANSWER! I went through literally a half-dozen other articles all with the exact same title (clean-up, guys!) with no joy until I found this one. Worked first time. I think there must be a bug in that the packager isn't setting the file permissions correctly on the source package before zipping...

Comment: I had the same problem, using cygwin's unzip! To fix both the exes and dlls:
`find $where_you_unzipped_eclipse \( -name "*.dll" -or -name "*.exe" \) -exec chmod +x {} \;`

Comment: plagues me too this problem with cygwin - here's a link to the bug report which they will probably never fix https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248237

Comment: Also here's the windows command I use to fix it instead of cygwin chmod: `icacls eclipse\plugins /T /Q /grant Everyone:F`

Answer (score 20):

I have seen this in MacOS Sierra. Sometimes unzipping the app leaves extended attributes that seem to prevent the startup. The following command line removes extended attributes and seems to fix the problem:

`xattr -c Eclipse.app`

It also works for other applications that are built on the eclipse framework.

Comment: It solved my problem. Using Macbook Pro with Sierra 10.12.4.

Comment: Worked with udig also. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked with udig on macos catalina

Answer (score 13):

Another problem (that I ran into) is that Cygwin's unzip utility (UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Cygwin. Original by Info-ZIP.) does not always correctly unzip everything needed for Eclipse to actually run.

Using [7ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) v9.20 got Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) up and running for me on Win7 64bit with 32bit JVM and 32bit Eclipse.

*(First time I've ever had Cygwin's unzip fail on me...)*

Comment: I had the same problem - unfortunately didn't notice your reply before  I figured it out. I'm guessing it has to do with line-endings. I noticed that eclipse.ini had Unix line endings after unzipping with Cygwin. Unzipped with Windows instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this myself and found that, indeed, as one post above stated: using cygwin and gunzip or unzip to set up your eclipse environment the permissions on the .exe and .dll files will be incorrect and the JVM will not run them properly.

## Quick solution:

```
#switch to the eclipse target folder
cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\) #or wherever you put eclipse
find ./ -regextype posix-extended -mindepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.exe|.*\.dll" |\
xargs chmod -v 750
```

Answer (score 6):

I meet this issue after copy a eclipse installation to another pc.I find the eclipse installation auto created the .p2 directory on my c:\Users\xx.p2, and --launcher.library refer to here.So it doesn't exist on my another pc.
My resolution is to reinstall eclipse:
a)Double click eclipse-inst-win64.exe
b)Click to change to advanced mode.
c)Uncheck the Bundle Pool
d)Finish your installation and copy again.
Everything will work well.

Comment: Similar problem here: Eclipse was installed with local admin account. Then it could not find the files that were installed in user's directory when started with my network account.

Comment: Some suggestions here about how to stop eclipse storing data under user folders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866324/change-location-where-eclipse-create-eclipse-p2-and-other-folders

Answer (score 4):

My experience and advice: Install Eclipse Juno on C: drive.

After download the zip, put it on C:, click the right mouse button -> extract here. Then a folder called eclipse will be created in C: drive.

Then go to Eclipse executable, run it, and all will be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem and solved it by running Eclipse as admin.

Comment: Worked for me too.  Thanks.  I wonder why this is.  If anyone knows how to fix this so we don't have to run as admin, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem happened when I unzipped using Cygwin.  Used the Windows XP standard unzip program and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> if you are having two eclipse then sometime this happens

you only have to remove

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar
```

from `eclipse.ini` file beside eclipse.exe(Launcher)

Answer (score 2):

Also see [this related question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876538/the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-launcher-jar#10877265).

The gist is: Try unzipping it again with a solid unzip tool. Sometimes unzipping goes wrong, especially with the built-in Windows Explorer tool.

Answer (score 1):

i have this error message when i use extract the files as follows:

- action\select all
- drag and drow the files to an new folder

Somehow information about the folders get lost

when i use "action\extract to..." it works.

Also, remember to right click on eclipse, then choose Security Unblock

Answer (score 1):

Try running `eclipse.exe` as administrator or using Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this is related to problems on windows with the unzipping it seems. (See other answers here for that).

The second largest issue seems to be that eclipse is not able to find java or finds a java version which is too old or even older eclipse installations.

Here's another take to the latter problem and a small twist to solve it. My work environment is on a linux system, without root access, and with software installations where I can configure which versions to use in a kind of config file. However I have no influence on the way those software packages are installed and they are immutable to me.

I download and untar the latest eclipse as usual to a user disk for which I have write permissions. Then I configure myself an alias to always temporarily cd into the eclipse installation when starting. That regardless of where I work on the file systems, eclipse always finds its correct libraries. It seems in some places, eclipses default search path for java digs out an installation (of java or older eclipses or sth else) in my environment that it really should not use.

Here's the alias:
alias eclipse '(pushd /enter_path_to_eclipse_install_dir_here/eclipse ; ./eclipse ; popd)'

Now you can start it normally from e.g. your project or arbitrary work directory:

```
eclipse
```

Or also put it in the background

```
eclipse &
```

Maybe this helps for people in convoluted work environments.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied the Eclipse folder from another machine where the path was different and that was the root of this problem. Changing the plugins path in ECLIPSE.INI worked for me !!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to install it on Windows 8.
But it was an zip composed file....
Ones I unzip and Run "eclipes.exe" file as run As 'Administrator' it was resolved. 
Now I  am enjoying it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Mac

Reason:
Eclipse copies from one location to other

Solution:
Paths change needed in /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

Fix path for plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message after a system restore with the eclipse folder (V. 3/2020) being located on a second drive (that was NOT restored at the same time, I use it for large files mainly).

Restoring the faulty installations C:\Users<user>.p2 folder to the new installation (referenced in eclipse.ini of the eclipse folder) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Keep shorter folder name, fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue recently: (In my case it was installation of STM32CubeMX software):

**what I faced:** I have two users in my laptop, I had installed the software in one user but on the hard disk partition: D:\
Now I had tried to work on another user!
-- I think you know why I got the error --
So as I was working on the 'other' user account, I got this error every time I tried to compile/build my project - obviously, Because I installed using one user and am working on another.

**Workaround:** Already mentioned in the above answers clearly!

**What I did differently:** I tried using the S/W in the other user, but there seems to be issues on the path file/location:
so I reinstalled the location in the user account I want to use and am running it properly now!

Note: While Installing it did ask about installing the software for all user/ current user :  I mistakenly had given 'current - user' =(

Answer (score 0):

I also faced ths problem, I just deleted the extracted file and extracted it again.

I have a .rar file.

This problem occurs when the file is not extracted completely.

Answer (score 0):

You might changed your drive-letter:
once u had installed eclipse on D:\, after windows reinstall the drive-letter is now E:\ (for example).

look into eclipse.ini in your eclipse folder, there are some lines where the drive-letter is still D:\

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to open eclipse.exe before the .zip file finished extracting.  Make sure all dependencies are unzipped or unpacked before opening the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on *Linux (CentOS 7 64 bit)* with *32-bit Eclipse Neon* and *32-bit JRE 8*. Non of the answers here or in similar questions were helpful, so I thought it can help someone.

Equinox launcher (`eclipse` executable) is reading the `plugins/` directory and then searches for `eclipse_xxxx.so/dll` in `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.<os>_<version>/`. Typically, the problem is in `eclipse.ini` pointing to the wrong version of *Equinox launcher* plugin. But, if the file system uses 64-bit inodes, such as XFS and one of the files gets `inode` number above 4294967296, then the launcher fails reading the `plugins/` directory and this error message pops up. Use `ls -li <eclipse>/plugins/` to check the `inode` numbers.

In my case, moving to another mount with `32-bit inodes` resolved the problem.

See: http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/sw/inodes64.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error with the Eclipse 4.10 installer.  We had failed to complete the install correctly due to platform security settings and attempted to uninstall but had to do it by hand since no uninstaller was introduced during the failed install.  We suspected this corrupted the end result - even after re-installing.

The solution was to use the JVM to launch Eclipse and bypass the launcher executable entirely.  The following command successfully launches Eclipse 4.10 (some parameters will change based on the version of Eclipse):

```
%JDK190%\bin\javaw.exe -jar C:\<fully_qualified_path_to_eclipse>\Eclipse410\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar -clean -showsplash
```

After using this command/shortcut to launch Eclipse we had no further errors with Eclipse itself but we weren't able to use the EXE launcher in the future.  Even after a year of using this version, the launcher continues to display this same error.

To be clear, you'll have to modify your `javaw.exe` command to match your system specifications on MS Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error sometime back. I had copied the eclipse setup from another laptop to mine. The issue with my setup was that path of the "--launcher.library" in the eclipse.ini file. The path in --launcher.library was that of the old machine and hence  I was getting the error

I changed the path of "--launcher.library" in eclipse.ini to the path of eclipse on my laptop and the issue got resolved. I hope this is helpful to someone is getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

> I have create ***Demo.exe*** using **Eclipse RCP**.

I have run **Demo.exe** using C-Drive to same error generate like...

[image]

**Solution :** You might changed your drive for example

```
 C:\Demo.exe to D:\Demo.exe
```

> Step 1 : First Copy/Cut your .exe file like **C:\Demo.exe**
>
> Step 2 : After Paste another drive like **D:\Demo.exe**

After executable file launching successfully.

I hope my answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  I read through all of the answers here.  Several of the answers allude to the need to run as admin.  It appears this is a common issue with IDEs in modern times on Windows.  I notice Android Studio also exhibits a very similar behavior.  While some individuals suggest reinstalling, that in itself doesn't feel very satisfying to me.  I have found a horrible "hack" to circumvent having to reinstall or having to run as admin.  If you copy the .p2 folder to the ALL USERS folder.  You then open the INI file and everywhere you see the admin user directory, replace with the ALL USERS directory.  While this feels somewhat hookey, I like this approach because it behaves like an installer that asks if you wish to install the product for the individual user or for all users.  The Eclipse installer does not give that option.  Worst still, worse than even a similar problem with Android Studio, is that if you choose some "shared folder" (like Program Files") for the install, then only that one user can ever use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is uninstall eclipse and delete the folder .p2 then installed again .

Answer (score -1):

open eclipse.ini and replace with this ~

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.0-531062
```

this work for me, good luck ~

Answer (score -2):

Restart the machine. Solve your problem. Sometimes it happens when you are trying to restart the eclipse and in-between forcefully close it.