# The Eclipse Executable Launcher Was Unable To Locate Its Companion Shared Library

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a java beginner and am going through the book "Java In 24 Hours Sixth Edition" by Rogers Cadenhead. I am on chapter 24 "Creating an Android app". The book has told me to download Eclipse and Android SDK on my computer and to unzip the zip files they come in. I have put them both in the same parent file (`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Downloads`). Then the book tells me I can run Eclipse now and I get a message instead saying

> "The Eclipse Executable Launcher Was Unable To Locate Its Companion
>   Shared Library".

Is there a way to fix this? Do I just have to re-install SDK and Eclipse? I have downloaded SDK for windows 64-bit and I have windows 64-bit. Any info on how to fix this would be most appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876538/the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-launcher-jar

Comment: The answer linked above merely says that WinRar does better, but that's not informative if you don't have WinRar but you do have both Windows integrated zip handling and Cygwin unzip.
I used Cygwin unzip and it failed. It made plenty of "directory structure" and the top level eclipse directory looks exactly like the top level directory that WinRAR made. So the answer linked above didn't say enough to keep me from trying Cygwin unzip. My guess is that handling of symlinks or executable attributes or such is where the failure arises.

Answer (score 1):

open eclipse.ini and caopy&paste this...

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

Make certain the .dll in the launcher.library directory has EXECUTE permissions. DLL's in Windows need execute permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the eclipse again. This message shows that the eclipse folder is not extracted correctly.

Comment: "Unzip the eclipse again" I assume you mean using a different utility? Just a minute ago I saw that the Eclipse website says to use 7Zip rather than the built-in Windows compressed folder utility, but no clear reason is given there.

Comment: I mean that downloading the eclipse again and unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't download the ADT bundle as the Eclipse that comes with that version is buggy the last time I tried it and I ended up deleting that Eclipse and downloading Eclipse Kepler on its own, and the SDK on its own

If you still can't solve it try:

Download  Eclipse and SDK separately and then follow instructions onthe SDK website to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error. For me it appeared to be a simple but rather strange problem. Eclipse requires "plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar" to launch (see eclipse.ini). For some reason the integrated windows unzip did not extract all the files from the plugins folder correctly. Running it again appeared to work for some reason. So check that all the files have been extracted correctly.