# Eclipse won't open

Tags: java

Eclipse was working perfectly yesterday and when I tried to open it this morning. This is what came up:

[image: Eclipse Link]

Can you please suggest a way of resolving this error.

Thanks

Comment: Please click on the link to see error message

Answer (score 0):

Click this link. Maybe what you are looking for is answered here.

[The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion launcher jar windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876538/the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-launcher-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Try just updating the `eclipse.ini` check for

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
```

then update the -vm option:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: I guess you should redownload the eclipse :( @PatrickLafferty

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I have beaten you to that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--clean` to your eclipse.ini that seems to solve a multitude of problems.