# Why am I getting an Error when starting terminal in mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, terminal

I get an eclipse error whenever I start my terminal in mac.
I get also an alert window saying:

The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion launcher.jar

in the terminal window the following error:
/Applications/IBM\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.rcp.base_10.0.0.20181128-1343/macosx/x86/eclipse ; exit;
ttt:~ husseinsalem$ /Applications/IBM\ Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/rcp/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.rcp.base_10.0.0.20181128-1343/macosx/x86/eclipse ; exit;
Unable to find any JVMs matching architecture "x86_64".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.

I did not update the system recently.
i did not upgrade my Notes.

Comment: It can't find a suitable Java.

Comment: The problem isn't Eclipse per se, it's the installation of IBM Notes. Notes is an application built using Eclipse RCP (Rich Client Platform).

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same situation and google leads me to this unanswered thread. Plenty of steps I've made and here I can just provide two cents instead of confident resolution.

The real question would be: Why is Eclipse executed when we purely click on the regular mac native "Terminal" app?

To make long story short, my conclusion is, maybe my Terminal shortcut in the Dock is hijacked somewhere somehow. I always have a habit to keep Terminal in Dock, instead of pressing F4 key and launching it from the "Other" folder in Launchpad. Eventually I removed the old Terminal icon from the Dock, execute a native one from Launchpad and pin this new icon from "Keep in Dock." Then my problem is gone. Reboot a couple of time and the one in Dock doesn't jump out Eclipse error any more.

---

Ideas of troubleshoot

My symptom was, Eclipse run and came out the error only for one time after a reboot. The error never happened again unless I reboot the mac.

What I did recently was

1. Upgraded IBM Notes from version 9 to 10. (Thanks to my laggy IT.)
2. Updated my Java through Java Control Panel inside System Preferences.

My immediate thought was "Does any environment get changed from the bash configuration profiles?" MacOS has a complicated initial steps. And I walked through all of the bash_profile and bashrc files for system-wide and user space. Can't find any trace of Eclipse. Then I tried to switch the execution between Dock and Launchpad. Replacing the shortcut in the Dock seems to fix my problem.

Yes. This still doesn't make sense why Eclipse error only pop up once if I always run the Terminal through the Dock. But I can't replicate this issue no longer. Here I just share some experiences since IBM sold Notes to the other company, their Q&A web pages get more and more broken and Google tends to show results of recent timeline but not helpful if the issue is tangled, unpopular or ancient.

Reference:

- https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/
- [The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion launcher jar windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876538/the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-launcher-jar)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050