# How to fix the Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library for windows 7?

Tags: eclipse, java

I am getting the following error, while launching Eclipse:

> The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

Previously Eclipse was working fine when I had `jre6` installed on my pc. After installing `jre7 update 25`, I am no longer able to launch Eclipse.

My Eclipse `ini`-file has these lines:

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
```

How do I fix this error? Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you install a 64-bit JRE7 by chance?

Comment: There are multiple reasons this may happen. Look at the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library One of them is probably the cause of your issue.

Comment: try by removing two lines -startup and the next one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29298234/3496570

Answer (score 13):

Had similar issue, which was a result of update. Please make sure that names of libraries mentioned in eclipse.ini and the actual names of these files on your disk match exactly.

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
```

Here is the post that I used to fix this issue on my system http://codewithgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/11/fixing-eclipse-executable-launcher-was.html

Comment: I found a solution in the comments in that link. In my case, '-starter' and '--launcher.library' had duplicate lines, which I removed. That seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It worked only after removing the eclipse folder and all related folders like .p2, .eclipse (in my case they are at different location where I have saved eclipse installer) etc. and after re-downloading the eclipse, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error occurred because of windows 7 shortcuts. In windows we create shortcuts on desktop by using right click > send to > desktop. In my pc, there is no option for desktop, but there is one for "documents". I created the shortcuts there and then moved them to the desktop. Executing these shortcuts causes the error. Eclipse works fine when I run it directly from the folder where it is installed. I fixed it by using right click > create shortcut and then moving this shortcut to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the 64 bit version of Kepler and windows7 in my case.
I downloaded the 32 bit and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

On the Zipped folder of the ADT you initially downloaded unzip and navigate to:

> adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\plugins

Copy all the executable jar files and paste them on the

> C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\plugins

directory (or wherever your adt is located).
Any executable jar files missing in the plugin folder will be added. You should be able to launch eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In my case **I have moved plugins folder mistakenly to another folder while taking backup of my unnecessary projects.** 
Then while I was trying to run the eclipse.exe I was getting the error-

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its  companion
>   shared library.

I have simply copied the plugins folder to eclipse root directory, and it was working fine for me.

If you have the folders backup in your computer then just copy and paste the folders on eclipse directory, you don't need to reinstall or change the ini file so far I realized.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when deleting some Equinox package from my `plugins` directory, make sure this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to that might be the 2 lines in eclipse.ini

```
--launcher.library
C:\Users\UserName\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

for my case the reason was admin privilages so I had to move the folder from the path specified in ini to my eclipse plugins and change path in ini to :

```
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar problem after installing new software. In my case, the problem was solved by: (1) restoring .p2 subdirectory under my home directory; and (2) editing eclipse.init file to have the updated java directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had copied a plugins folder into workspace from a collegue. Becaouse it was an unzipped folder, the structure was like 'pluginsfolder inside a plugins folder2 . so make sure that all the plugins are directly located under the toppest plugins folder at the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case eclipse.ini entry for --launcher.library was :

--launcher.library
C:\Users\UserName\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834

and on my machine 'C:\Users\UserName\.p2\' folder was missing hence installed the eclipse again which created the .p2 folder structure at required location and now I am able to login successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps and it worked for me.

**Step1:**
Edit eclipse.ini by adding javaw.exe path and remove --launcher.appendVmargs line.
Below shows the original and edited file

Orginal eclipse.ini
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

After editing eclipse.ini:
openFile
-vm
C:/ProgramFiles/Java/javapath/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

**Step2:**
Copied the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar to  eclipse installation folder .
You can find the .jar location in eclipse.ini
eg : C:\Users\Username.p2\pool\plugins