# Cannot open Eclipse after opening once? (Error included)

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, zip, 7zip

After opening Eclipse **once and without updating**, it does not open again.  It spits out the error "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library." and does not open.  I have Windows and used 7-Zip to unzip the file (I have read that windows default unzip tool corrupts the file).  I would like to emphasize that it works **once and without updating**, but then if closed, will not open again.  Thanks for any answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very weird behavior.

The `The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library` error popup does indeed happen when you don't expand the archive according to Windows' bizarre requirements, and it seems you've documented yourself well enough before posting this.

I would advise:

- erasing the eclipse folder
- copying the downloaded archive to a "safe" folder like "My Documents"
- right-clicking the archive there, and "extract here"
- moving the extracted folder back to its location (32-bit or 64-bit
  Program Files)
- trying to launch again

Comment: It worked fine until I dragged the eclipse application part to the desktop.  Would that cause a problem?

Comment: @user2665414 Not sure I understand. Did you drag the folder to the desktop or just the binary?

Comment: It's the actual application part (It's a bad description I know).  When the folder is open with the Eclipse sign?  I'm going to try just running from documents though.  And that worked.  I just can't copy it to my desktop.  But still solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Don't drag just the Eclipse executable to the desktop, create a link (shortcut) if you want a copy on the desktop.  Eclipse's executable launcher must live in the directory containing all of Eclipse.

Comment: @JimGarrison aah now I understand what OP meant. +1 for your comment, totally agree, the binary must be in its own folder.