# the Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library error message

Tags: eclipse, message, executable, launcher

I decided to turn over a new leaf and start learning Java, but after downloading eclipse I cannot seem to make it run. I originally got an error saying it couldn't find my VM so I changed the path in the eclipse.ini to where "Java Mission Control" is installed, and now it's giving me this error when I try to run the application. I have looked at many other posts where people get the same error message but they all have to do with wrongly unzipped files and I am quite sure I unzipped it properly. I have also tried different mirrors and redownloaded eclipse 5 or 6 times as well as reinstalled JDK with no avail. I have used WinZip, Windows file explorer, and Jzip all to unzip the file with the same message.

Windows 7 64bit
8gb ram,i7, 660ti graphics

Comment: The fact that Eclipse cannot find your JVM is an indication that Java is _not_ properly installed. To which folder did you install it? How, running an installer? Is it a 64bit JVM?

Comment: Had similar problem once, solved when downloaded a '32bit' eclipse for java EE developers...

Comment: figured it out for whatever reason JDK 1.7 doesn't work with eclipse on my computer only 1.6 i had to download an older version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library)

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste all of the contents into a folder on your desktop, you can then use the eclipse.exe file just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Eclipse. I even had a very similar problem when trying to install the Android Studio (I wanted to compare Eclipse and Android Studio). The difference with Android Studio was the error message (forgot exactly, but was saying that I was missing a .dll file that was important).

The simple thing that solved the problem:
I moved the original .zip file out of the folder where the unzipped files were created (I moved to the desktop). You can even delete it definitely because once unzipped we don't need it anymore. Then, the Eclipse.exe run smoothly (even before running it I noticed its icon changed after I eliminated the .zip). Then I went and did the same for Android Studio, run the corresponding .exe file, and tara-raaaan: run too!!!

Easy... but not obvious at all, I know. Hope this helps!

PD: Before this problem I had another one. It was related with Java (JDK); I had to add the path where it was installed and that solved the problem.