# iMac: The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Something weird happen to me, I just download `eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz`, and install on the iMac `macOS Sierra 10.12`.

It prompts `The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library` when I open the eclipse app.

I have been searched a lot before asking, like [Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library)

But still cannot figure it out, anyone have idea?

Comment: Why are you installing a two year old release? Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 is the current release.

Comment: i'm having the same problem with an EXPORTED Eclipse RCP product. So... all ok in previous versions of MacOS... This error happens with SIERRA only. I can start from Contents/MacOS/app in a terminal window, but i want a solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by multiple things, I'd suggest unzipping it again with a different application to make sure that it's extracted correctly. On the Mac, I usually use Keka.

Comment: In my case, i have an installer for MAC (RCP app) and all works fine in releases previous to MacOS SIERRA!