# How to fix Eclipse Error: The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library? Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, installation, windows-10

How do I fix the error "The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" on Windows 10. I wasn't able to find it elsewhere and I would appreciate it if someone can explain it to me in layman's terms. TIA

Comment: I guess that means, the `eclipse.exe` does not find a library it was linked against and fails even before the Java VM is started. With other words, your Eclipse installation is broken.

Comment: how do i fix it was the original question

Comment: Your Eclipse installation is broken means you have to re-install and maybe also re-download it. In case you have a ZIP file, you have to unzip it first (the error you get is also shown when the `eclipse.exe` will be run without the other files).

Comment: Eclipse [uses an installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer) not zip files. The installer can also repair the broken installation. Windows typically caches installation files just for this reason, so even if you delete the installer you may be able to repair the installation. [Go to Apps & Features, find the Eclipse entry and click Repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/repair-apps-and-programs-in-windows-10-e90eefe4-d0a2-7c1b-dd59-949a9030f317)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The point is that with saying _"not zip files"_ and _"Go to Apps"_ you claim to know. But both are wrong and you were just guessing blindly. That is an absolute no-go and not helpful at all.

Comment: Both what @PanagiotisKanavos says is wrong: Eclipse uses also [ZIP files](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and _repair application_ does not apply to the Eclipse Installer.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error message, ofter, occurs when Eclipse bundle that you downloaded was not correctly unzipped.

Try to simply delete the Eclipse folder and then extract it again with a well known unzip tool (have a look at the extension of the file, if it's tar, rar or zip and use a extract tool that supports it).
Finally you can try running eclipse.exe

Comment: I didn't know I needed the original Eclipse software. I might have deleted it. Should I re-download it?

Comment: @BezawitGirma Eclipse uses an installer, not ZIP files. Installers [can also repair applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/repair-apps-and-programs-in-windows-10-e90eefe4-d0a2-7c1b-dd59-949a9030f317)

Comment: Both what @PanagiotisKanavos says is wrong: Eclipse uses also [ZIP files](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and _repair application_ does not apply to the Eclipse Installer.