# Eclipse cannot start in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Eclipse cannot start in Ubuntu and gives an error log - `java.lang classNotFoundException`

```
!SESSION Sat Nov 17 14:47:28 EAT 2012 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2012-11-17 14:47:28.694
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte)

Comment: Except the resolution steps for windows, in @gks ' duplicate, do not help on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your home directory if there is some eclipse file or folder and delete them. You can see them with "CTRL + H" on your /home.

Or try to clean your workspace.

Or try to delete the .snap file located in the directory :
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources

Or try to reinstall

Or try to upgrade