# Eclipse doesn't open suddenly Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have been using eclipse for the past 3 months  but suddenly eclipse gives and error and the log file reads :

!SESSION Tue Feb 12 20:43:32 IST 2013 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2013-02-12 20:43:32.273
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Answer (score 1):

Search before asking next time, many answers to be found.
And if you tried some, tell us.

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte)

In your `config.ini` file of eclipse `eclipse\configuration\config.ini` 
check this three things:

```
osgi.framework=file\:plugins\\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.0.v20080604.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\\bundles.info
```

And check whether these jars are in place or not, the jar files depend upon your version of eclipse .