# Eclipse error occurs when trying to launch?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to configure Eclipse at work and we've been having nothing but issues. I finally was able to run some updates inside of Eclipse by modifying some permissions. After the updates were done, Eclipse needed to restart in order to apply the updates. Now each time I try to launch it, it gives a message saying the following:

```
An error has occurred. See the logfile C:\Users\%user%\Eclipse\eclipse\null\123.log
```

Here are the contents of the log file:

```
!SESSION Wed May 13 12:37:30 CDT 2015 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-05-13 12:37:30.823
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-05-13 12:37:30.900
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: You have 64bit java with 64 bit eclipse? If you have both 32 and 64 you need to set the one eclipse need as you path

Comment: I'm using 64-bit for both Java and Eclipse.

I do have this path in my PATH variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte