# Eclipse giving java 8 support error won't start

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

These are my config.ini files, logs, and error I'm receiving.  I was able to open and build a basic test yesterday, albeit giving binary error, but I'm receiving these errors again today trying to open eclipse.  I have reinstalled java and eclipse multiple times all because of these errors.  I'm running ubuntu 18.04, java 1.8.0_181, and eclipse 4.7.  Can you help me get my eclipse running please?

configi.ini file...

```
 #This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl
 #Wed Aug 22 19:16:40 PDT 2018
 org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
 eclipse.p2.profile=_home_ryan_eclipse_cpp-oxygen_eclipse
 osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
 osgi.framework=file\:/home/ryan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.100.v20180210-1608.jar
 equinox.use.ds=true
 eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
 ds.delayed.keepInstances=true
 osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.2.1.v20180131-1435.jar@1\:start
```

log...

```
!SESSION Thu Aug 23 15:58:45 PDT 2018 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-08-23 15:58:45.890
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=file\:/home/ryan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.7.3.v20180330-0640
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.0.v20170516-1513.jar
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=file\:/home/ryan/.p2/osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

error when opening eclipse...
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/ryan/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1535066792371.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte