# Problem with starting eclipse on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I have a linux mint OS 64 bit system with Ubuntu and am trying to run the eclipse application from the menu but every time it gives me a pop-up error message stating:

**An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/corp/user/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1541803035391.log**

the contents of this log file are:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-11-09 14:37:15.409
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53234236/edit) your question and include the log file as text instead of as an image.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Does this answer fix your problem? If so I can mark this as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722827/1092820

Comment: Ubuntu's version of Eclipse is *ancient*--3.8 compared to the current 4.9--and not compatible with modern versions of Java. If you are using Java 9 or above, download the current release from download.eclipse.org.

Comment: do you usually use eclipse on this platform or are you just using it for the first time? Also is this the mint-provided version of eclipse, or did you download from the eclipse site?

Comment: Ruzhihm: that answer did not help, seems like the config.ini file is correct

Comment: John: I just got this system at work, when I first downloaded eclipse I did not use the one found in the Software Manager because it had this problem, I instead downloaded the current version from the eclipse site and tarred it just following the steps of a video on youtube. I can share this is if needed. It all worked fine at first then the next time I tried to launch that version of eclipse from the menu it was not there and going through the same process doesnt bring it back. So now I am trying to use the one found in the software manager.

Comment: nitind: you are right the version that they offer on ubuntu is really old. I did install it originally from eclipses website and it worked fine but then had problems opening it later. I would always have to launch it through the terminal and it is not ideal for me.