# Error when starting Eclipse from favorites toolbar java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-18.04

When I run Eclipse CDT 2018-12 from the directory it works perfectly fine:

/home/fatih/eclipse/cpp-2018-12/eclipse/eclipse

When I add the very same, i.e. the recently started session of Eclipse, to the favorites toolbar, I cannot start by clicking on the eclipse icon on the favorites toolbar.

I want to ask how I can still start from the favorites toolbar by solving these errors.

I get the following error message:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/fatih/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1549048971236.log

    !SESSION Fri Feb 01 20:22:51 CET 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-02-01 20:22:51.266
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
```

When I open the log message the following can be found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I have also followed the contents from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte/42517122) other threads. However, this also does not solve the problem in my case. Therefore, it is also not a double of those two threads. Just for completeness, I would also like to add the content of the config.ini and eclipse.ini files below:

config.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl
#Fri Feb 01 19:51:30 CET 2019
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=file\:/home/fatih/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.10.0.v20181206-0815
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:/home/fatih/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.200.v20181101-1115.jar@1\:start
eclipse.p2.data.area=file\:/home/fatih/.p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=_home_fatih_eclipse_cpp-2018-12_eclipse
osgi.framework=file\:/home/fatih/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.13.200.v20181130-2106.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:/home/fatih/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.300.v20181116-1550.jar
eclipse.buildId=4.10.0.I20181206-0815
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar
--launcher.library
/home/fatih/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.900.v20180922-1751
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the version of Eclipse, download the [2020-12 version](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-12/R/eclipse-inst-jre-linux64.tar.gz) and navigate to the download folder and unpack the file with :

```
tar -xvf eclipse-inst-jre-linux64.tar.gz
```

Now go into the `eclipse-installer` folder and type :

```
./eclipse-inst
```

This will prompt the installer and you are good to go after that.